# How can I find the square roots of the following complex number?

Tags: complex-numbers

How do I find the square roots of a complex number defined as followed: $z=(1,1)$ ?

I am a bit confused the way the number is defined. Shouldn't a complex number be defined like this: $z=a+ib$ ?

Comment: $(1,1)$ means the same thing as $a+bi$.  Plot $(1,1)$ on the argand plane.

Comment: (1,1) corresponds to the complex number $1+i$.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that is asked in the context of identifying $\mathbb C$ with $\mathbb R^2$, in which case $(1,1)=1+i$. So, use the fact that $1+i=\sqrt2\left(\cos\left(\frac\pi4\right)+\sin\left(\frac\pi4\right)i\right)$.

Answer (score 0):

We you define a complex number in the form:
$$z:(1,1)$$
this is the same as:
$$z=1+i=\sqrt2(\cos(\pi/4)+i\sin(\pi/4))$$
To compute the square root, we define:
$$w=r(\cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta))\leftrightarrow w^2=r^2(\cos(2\theta)+i\sin(2\theta))$$
We impose $w^2=z$ and we have:
$$r=\sqrt[4]{2}$$
and:
$$\theta=\pi/8+k\pi, k=0,1\leftrightarrow \theta=\pi/8 \vee \theta=9\pi/8$$
Substituing the values of $r$ and $\theta$ we have done.